# How to migrate my mongoose PROMISE chain transactions to ASYNC / AWAIT flow?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I created an API that integrate database responses in a promise flow, but I think the interpretation of the code is complex and I believe that async / await approach could improve both understanding and the code itself.

The API is built in NodeJS using mongoose 5.6.1 and express 4.17.1.

Can you help me in improve this?

Below is the API that I want to improve:

```
/** New employee */
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let { idCompany, name, departament } = req.body;
    let _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(); // Generating new MongoDB _ID
    let employeeCreated;

    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Querying by document '$oid'
        Companies.findOne({ _id: idCompany }, (err, company) => {
            // Error returned
            if (err) reject({ error: "Invalid request, something went wrong!" });
            // Invalid data received
            if (!company) reject({ error: "Unauthorized action!" });
            // Everything OK
            resolve(company);

        });
    })
    .then(company => {
        if(company) {
            const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Employees.create({ _id, idCompany, name, departament }, (err, employee) => {
                    // Error returned
                    if (err) reject({ error: "Invalid request, something went wrong!", err });
                    // Everything OK
                    employeeCreated = employee;
                    resolve(company);
                });
            })
            return promise2;
        }else reject({ error: "Company not found!" });
    })
    .then(company => {
        let { name: companyName, address, email, tel, employees } = company;
        employees.push(_id);

        const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Companies.findByIdAndUpdate(
                { _id: idCompany },
                { $set: { _id: idCompany, name: companyName, address, email, tel, employees } }, // spotlight
                { new: true },
                (err, company) => {
                    // Something wrong happens
                    if (err) reject({ success: false, error: "Can't update company!" });
                    // Everything OK
                    resolve(company);
                }
            );
        });
        return promise3;
    });

    promise1
        .then(() => res.json({ success: true, employeeCreated }))
        .catch(err =>   res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid request, something went wrong!", err }));
});
```

Regards.

Comment: Do you use an IDE? I know VS Code provides a refactoring tool.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt was made.

Comment: @jhpratt you are being confused. How VS Code can fully refactor an 2 layer promise async chain into sync async/await flow? That's a programming technique question, not 'IDE do it for me' question.

Comment: First of all, `async/await` is not sync, even if it may look like it. I was merely suggesting a tool that could help you so you don't have to do it by hand, not saying that it's the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key to using promises with mongoose, is using the [`exec`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) method:

Your code could then look something like this (not tested):

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { idCompany, name, departament } = req.body;
        const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        const company = await Companies.findOne({ _id: idCompany }).exec();
        const employeeCreated = await Employees.create({ _id, idCompany, name, departament });
        const { name: companyName, address, email, tel, employees } = company;
        employees.push(_id);
        await Companies.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    { _id: idCompany },
                    { $set: { _id: idCompany, name: companyName, address, email, tel, employees } }, // spotlight
                    { new: true }).exec();
        res.json({ success: true, employeeCreated });
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid request, something went wrong!", err });
    }
});
```

You could throw some specific custom errors in the `try` block if you find that necessary.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, I was not aware of the `exec` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make the functions where your promises are running async and so, you could await for the promises to resolve.

For example, in your route use this:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
```

and then when performing an async operation, use this:

```
const company = await Companies.findOne({ _id: idCompany }).exec();
```

Also, I would suggest you to wrap this with try and catch statments

Hope it helps!